# Async function as a function pointer type: what is the correct type definition?

Tags: rust, function-pointers

I have a set of handlers that are defined as

```
async fn handler1(req: Request<'_>, state: web::Data<State>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error<'_>> {
    ...
}
async fn handler2(req: Request<'_>, state: web::Data<State>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error<'_>> {
    ...
}
```

What I'm trying is to return a pointer to such handler from a match statement:

```
type MethodHandler = fn(req: Request<'_>, state: web::Data<State>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error<'_>>;

fn select_handler(method: &str) -> Option<MethodHandler> {
    match method {
        "handler1" => Some(handler1),
        "handler2" => Some(handler2),
        _ => None
    }
}
```

It does not goes very well because of async nature of handlers:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/handlers.rs:384:34
     |
1084 |         "handler1" => Some(handler1),
     |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found opaque type
     |
     = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(handlers::Request<'r>, actix_web::web::Data<_>) -> std::result::Result<HttpResponse, handlers::Error<'r>>`
                   found fn item `for<'_> fn(handlers::Request<'_>, actix_web::web::Data<_>) -> impl futures_util::Future {handler1}`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/handlers.rs:385:38
     |
1085 |         "handler1" => Some(handler1),
     |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found opaque type
     |
     = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(handlers::Request<'r>, actix_web::web::Data<_>) -> std::result::Result<HttpResponse, handlers::Error<'r>>`
                   found fn item `for<'_> fn(handlers::Request<'_>, actix_web::web::Data<_>) -> impl futures_util::Future {handler2}`
```

So I have two questions:

1. What will be the correct type definition for `MethodHandler`?
2. Maybe I'm totally trying to invent the wheel here and there are already some libraries / common patters for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You cannot do that. Async functions return anonymous implementations of the `Future` trait, so your `MethodHandler` type alias is wrong. Also each anonymous future is a distinct type, so you cannot use your `MethodHandler` for both async functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, each `async` block and function returns an anonymous type that you cannot name. Although even if you could, each of them is unique so you wouldn't be able to have a single return type anyway. You will need to box the futures and use dynamic dispatch.

The easiest solution is [`BoxFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.16/futures/future/type.BoxFuture.html) from the `futures` crate which handles pinning and lifetimes for you. This will make your type definition

```
type MethodHandler = fn(req: Request<'_>, state: State)
                -> BoxFuture<Result<HttpResponse, Error<'_>>>;
```

and you will need to de-sugar your `async` functions to return a boxed future instead by using [`FutureExt::boxed`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.16/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.boxed):

```
fn handler1(_req: Request<'_>, _state: State) -> BoxFuture<Result<HttpResponse, Error<'_>>> {
    async move {
        // Old function body
    }.boxed()
}
```

You can find a compiling example, although missing the real types, at [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f760d4d203467a1a1b8d80135be57c3e).